# Hibernate 5.x reference documentation in detail w/ examples

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have started migrating my code to 5.x version of hibernate, however I do not find the official reference documentation (i.e. user guide) comprehensive.
Is there any reference which is in detail and with examples ? Does hibernate also provide a set of sample code like for Spring we have PetClinic store example.
currently i am referring to this -> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you do not find in the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

Comment: it gives a high level reference of the concepts (which is informative) although if there are examples which can be referred to will make things more clear. For e.g. in case of customUserType , basicType, interceptor what is the way to implement  it & if i still want to go with XML mapping file way what is the way to register it?